# How to see exceptions raised from a channels consumer

Tags: django, exception, django-channels

I begin to use `django-channels` and I find it fantastic. However debugging consumers is painful because when some exceptions are raised from inside a consumer, nothing is printed to the terminal, the websocket is simply disconnected.

The kind of exception not shown is not obvious to identify. It is the case systematically for `AssertionError`, and also some others, for example the code below:

```
class MexicoProgressConsumer(ProgressConsumer):
    def init(self, SSDBConfig, Sub_application):
        subappli = models.Sub_application.objects.get(pk=Sub_application)
        ...
```

Calling this method with a wrong number of arguments does not print anything on the console and disconnect the websocket. Idem if the `get` on the last line fails.

Is there a way to see those exceptions as any other ones?

Comment: Can you give an example code where the exception is not shown? I get the most of the exceptions raised

Comment: Yes you are right, I realize that most of exception work, except systematically `AssertionError`, and some other cases I no more remember. No luck, I use `assert` quite often.

Comment: Can you give any concrete example with code to support it?

Comment: The problem is that there is nothing to show because it happens nothing. I fall on another exception not shown: wrong number of argument in a consumer method call.

Comment: You could post the code and example values that should throw the error

Comment: Question edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. I first define a decorator:

```
import traceback
def catch_exception(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        except StopConsumer:
            raise
        except Exception as e:
            print(traceback.format_exc().strip('\n'), '<--- from consumer')
            raise
    return wrapper
```

Then I define a base class for all my consumers, that uses this decorator this way:

```
import inspect
class BaseConsumer(JsonWebsocketConsumer):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        value = object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        if inspect.ismethod(value):
            return catch_exception(value)
        return value
```

But 2 problems persist:

- Exceptions normally shown appear twice
- Other exceptions are repeated 3 or 4 times! (as if each level of class hierarchy fires)

Exemple of the first case (KeyError):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alain/ADN/simutool/dbsimu/consumers.py", line 19, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alain/ADN/simutool/dbsimu/consumers.py", line 31, in wrapper
    result = f(owner, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alain/ADN/simutool/dbsimu/consumers.py", line 110, in refresh
    data = super().refresh.__wrapped__(self)
  File "/home/alain/ADN/simutool/dbsimu/consumers.py", line 73, in refresh
    pvalue = round(data['toto'] * 100, 1)
KeyError: 'toto' <--- from consumer
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/alain/ADN/simutool/dbsimu/utils.py", line 193, in repeat
    self.repeat_func()
  File "/home/alain/ADN/simutool/dbsimu/consumers.py", line 19, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alain/ADN/simutool/dbsimu/consumers.py", line 31, in wrapper
    result = f(owner, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alain/ADN/simutool/dbsimu/consumers.py", line 110, in refresh
    data = super().refresh.__wrapped__(self)
  File "/home/alain/ADN/simutool/dbsimu/consumers.py", line 73, in refresh
    pvalue = round(data['toto'] * 100, 1)
KeyError: 'toto'
```

Example of the second case (misspelled variable):

```
WebSocket CONNECT /ws/dbsimu/Simuflow_progress/ [127.0.0.1:55866]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alain/ADN/simutool/dbsimu/consumers.py", line 19, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alain/ADN/simutool/dbsimu/consumers.py", line 57, in receive_json
    return getattr(self, icommand)(**data)
NameError: name 'icommand' is not defined <--- from consumer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alain/ADN/simutool/dbsimu/consumers.py", line 19, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alain/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/generic/websocket.py", line 125, in receive
    self.receive_json(self.decode_json(text_data), **kwargs)
  File "/home/alain/ADN/simutool/dbsimu/consumers.py", line 19, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alain/ADN/simutool/dbsimu/consumers.py", line 57, in receive_json
    return getattr(self, icommand)(**data)
NameError: name 'icommand' is not defined <--- from consumer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alain/ADN/simutool/dbsimu/consumers.py", line 19, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alain/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/generic/websocket.py", line 60, in websocket_receive
    self.receive(text_data=message["text"])
  File "/home/alain/ADN/simutool/dbsimu/consumers.py", line 19, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alain/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/generic/websocket.py", line 125, in receive
    self.receive_json(self.decode_json(text_data), **kwargs)
  File "/home/alain/ADN/simutool/dbsimu/consumers.py", line 19, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alain/ADN/simutool/dbsimu/consumers.py", line 57, in receive_json
    return getattr(self, icommand)(**data)
NameError: name 'icommand' is not defined <--- from consumer
```

If somebody has any idea to fix that, please advise.

Comment: Probably because you are overriding `__getattribute__` which is called each time an attribute is got. Instead of a base class, I would define a class decorator that applies the exception catching decorator to each method when the class (NOT instances of the class) is created at import time. Similar to [python_2_unicode_compatible](https://github.com/benjaminp/six/blob/master/six.py#L923) in the six library.

Comment: After more investigation, I believe the reason you are getting the exceptions printed more than once, is they are getting raised up through several levels of function calls, and getting logged at every level. See my answer for a different solution

Answer (score 7):

Starting with albar's [answer](/questions/54458852/how-to-see-exceptions-raised-from-a-channels-consumer/54494878#54494878), the solution I reached was to define a decorator like so

```
from functools import wraps
from logging import getLogger

from channels.exceptions import AcceptConnection, DenyConnection, StopConsumer

logger = getLogger("foo-logger")

def log_exceptions(f):
    @wraps(f)
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return await f(*args, **kwargs)
        except (AcceptConnection, DenyConnection, StopConsumer):
            raise
        except Exception as exception:
            if not getattr(exception, "logged_by_wrapper", False):
                logger.error(
                    "Unhandled exception occurred in {}:".format(f.__qualname__),
                    exc_info=exception,
                )
                setattr(exception, "logged_by_wrapper", True)
            raise

    return wrapper
```

This has several improvements:

- Uses functools.wraps which makes the wrapped function more closely resemble the original function.
- Uses async/await syntax since I'm using Async Consumers (remove if you aren't)
- Doesn't log for several exceptions django-channels raises on purpose.
- Only logs the exception if it doesn't have the attribute `logged_by_wrapper` set. This causes the exception to only be logged once since we set the attribute after logging the first time.
- Uses python's built-in `logging` module to log the errors. This automatically formats the exception and the traceback since we provide the exception in `exc_info=exception`.

Then instead of a base Class I defined a class decorator to apply this to a Consumer's methods

```
from inspect import iscoroutinefunction

def log_consumer_exceptions(klass):
    for method_name, method in list(klass.__dict__.items()):
        if iscoroutinefunction(method):
            setattr(klass, method_name, log_exceptions(method))

    return klass
```

This applies `log_exceptions` to all async methods defined in the Consumer, though not to methods it inherits - ie only to our custom methods for the Consumer.