# Django channels blocks on database access

Tags: django-channels

I am upgrading current project from channel v1 to v3 and I am bit stuck here

```py
class MultiplexConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):

    def connect(self):
        print(11111111, self.scope)
        logger.debug("Received new connection request from {}", self.channel_name)
        WebSocketsConnection.objects.create(channel_id=self.channel_name, last_pong=datetime.datetime.now())
        print(444444444)
        self.accept()
        print(555555555)

   ...
```

```py
class WebSocketsConnection(models.Model):
    """
        This model exists because Django channels does not provide a default way to handle user presence.
    """
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    channel_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.deletion.SET_NULL)
    last_pong = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    data = JSONField(default={})

    def ping(self):
        channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
        async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)(self.channel_id, create_action('API', APIConstants.PING), immediately=True)

    def pong(self):
        self.last_pong = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def get_groups(self):
        groups = []
        for sub in WebSocketsConnectionSubscription.objects.filter(ws_connection=self):
            groups.append(sub.get_group_id())
        return groups

    def _add_subscription(self, data, sub_type):
        try:
            sub = WebSocketsConnectionSubscription.objects.get(ws_connection=self, type=sub_type)
            sub.data = data
            sub.save()
        except WebSocketsConnectionSubscription.DoesNotExist:
            WebSocketsConnectionSubscription.objects.create(ws_connection=self, data=data, type=sub_type)
```

It never prints `444444444`, if I remove the `WebSocketsConnection` model creation statement, it flows fine. Any ideas?

I checked there are not model signals attached to `WebSocketsConnection`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find out the problem, the value of `self.channel_name` is too long for the field `channel_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)`

Once I changed it to 100 chars then it worked fine, but why it was not throwing any errors was still unknown.

UPDATE: It's a known problem that consumers not propagating the error up [How to see exceptions raised from a channels consumer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54458852/how-to-see-exceptions-raised-from-a-channels-consumer)